# How to abort a makefile when a command failed?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like to check if a third-party library is available before launching the compilation. It easy to do with `pkg-config` but I would like a better error message than:

```
pkg-config gtk+-3.0
make: *** [Makefile:17: gtk+-3.0] Error 1
```

After reading some answers here, I found a satisfying code to do that:

```
gtk+-3.0:
    $(shell pkg-config $@)
    ifneq ($(.SHELLSTATUS),0)
        $(error $@ is not installed)
    endif
```

But the error is always triggered.

If I replace `$(error)` by `echo` I have a syntax error:

```
ifneq (0,0)
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `0,0'
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `ifneq (0,0)'
make: *** [Makefile:3: gtk+-3.0] Error 1
```

GNU Make 4.2.1 on archlinux.

Comment: I don't understand the use of `$(shell ...` here.  Just use `pkg-config $@` as the command and drop the `ifneq ...` stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a part of the question: "abort *with a understandable message for users*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Make* already stops when a command fails. Just write

```
gtk+-3.0:
        pkg-config $@
```

Or for more control of the message,

```
gtk+-3.0:
        @if pkg-config $@; then \
           printf '%s\n' "All good!"; \
        else \
           printf '%s\n' "Not installed." >&2; \
           exit 1; \
        fi
```

Note that *make* always uses a Bourne shell (probably `/bin/sh`) so there is no need for `$(shell)` for simple commands. Using *make*-conditionals is also not done as you seem to expect. The GNU *make* manual has all the details.